# Drop Down List Selected Value is Null Problem

Tags: asp.net

Dropdwon list binding with null value in database
**solution:**
***`select job_id,job_name from jobs union select null as none ,null as none`***

Comment: what is your question here? there is no indication at all

Comment: lol. ah. this is by far the best description ever... NOT. More information needed.

Answer (score 4):

Drop Down List Selected Value Is Null Solution.